# Adding and overriding functions in existing plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my my plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

        this.foo()
        {
            alert('test');
        }


    }
    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
    };
});
```

Now I want to extend it without touching the original plugin i.e I want the full feature of existing plugin + the new features which I want. Below are the new things I need:

**First**: 
Name of the new plugin "myPlugin2"

**Second**:
The "foo" function of the existing plugin should be overridden in the new plugin with this:

```
function foo() {
    alert('test2');
}
```

**Third**:
I need to add one more method to my new plugin say function foo2(){} .

Can you help me in achieving this?

Comment: That code is not syntactically valid.

Comment: have you looked at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring ? it may help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your default name and foo events in your defaults declaration:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
  name: 'test',
  onFoo: function() {
           alert(this.name);
         },
  onFoo2: function() {
           // your default behaviour for foo2
         }
};
```

Then, when someone calls your plugin, they can override the defaults, in this case `name`:

```
  $("#myControl").myPlugin({
    name: 'test2'
  });
```

Note that they don't need to override onFoo, because it will display an alert with test2. Anyway, if they need to override it to do something different, then they should:

```
  $("#myControl").myPlugin({
    name: 'test2',
    onFoo: function() {
             alert('onFoo overrired');
           },
    onFoo2: function() {
             alert('onFoo2 overrired');
           }
  });
```

In your plugin, you invoke the foo methods as

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

        // if onFoo is defined then call it
        if (opt.onFoo) {
          opt.onFoo();
        }

        // if onFoo2 is defined then call it
        if (opt.onFoo2) {
          opt.onFoo2();
        }
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
       name: 'test',
       onFoo: function() {
                alert(this.name);
              },
       onFoo2: function() {
                // your default behaviour for foo2
              }
    };
});
```

You should use this technique for public methods/properties that you want to expose to the users of your plugin.
I didn't tested but should work

**Edit**
You need to check if the event is set before calling it:

```
// if onFoo is defined (not null) then call it
if (opt.onFoo) {
  opt.onFoo();
}
```

You are setting already an event for onFoo and onFoo2, but the user of your plugin might choose to disable it:

```
  $("#myControl").myPlugin({
    onFoo: null
  });
```

In this case, although you have defined an `onFoo` event, the user of your plugin decided to ignore it, by setting it to `null`. So, even though you have defined an event, you never know what others will do with it, therefore it's better to be on the safe side and check for nullity.

Once again, you need to be careful with what you expose to the end user, because setting/unsetting events should not break the basic functionality of your plugin

Comment: One question what is the need of these too  if (opt.onFoo) {          opt.onFoo();        } since I am already doing $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

Comment: @Rocky Singh  See the clarification that I added in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If this is any decently coded plugin, you shouldn't be able to alter it's methods. It should of made anything which isn't meant to be invoked an internal function i.e.:

```
$.fn.oldPlugin = function() {

    var foo = function() {
       alert('old code');
    };
};
```

There is no way to invoke `foo` or overwrite it.

Should you not need to change any of the methods/functions then you can use `$.extend($.fn.pluginName, {/*your methods/properties*/};`

What it all really comes down to is:

- How the plugin you want to extend is coded
- If you want to overwrite or just extend on it's functionality